# ResourceBundle - How to point getBundle to android's resources

Tags: android, android-resources, resourcebundle

I am trying to make use of the `ResourceBundle` class in my application. I am still confused/stuck in instantiating the whole thing. Especially pointing the `ResourceBundle` to my res folder where I have `values-en`, `values-fr`, `values-sw` and so on.

I have tried the following:

```
resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(basename, locale);
```

where `basename`:

```
"myclasspackage"
"res"
"/data/data/myclasspackage/project.properties"
```

All of the initializations give me the same, `NullPointerExpection`. Please please help me.

Answer (score 2):

`ResourceBundle` is for old-style Java resources in JAR files and have nothing to do with Android's resource system.

Comment: how do i access my `res` file then?

Comment: @user2247689: "how do i access my res file then?" -- there is no `res` file to access. What is in the `res/` directory of your project is packaged into Android resources, which you reference in XML files (e.g., `@string/foo`) or Java (e.g., `R.string.foo`) where needed.

Comment: I want to get the english equivalent of a french word from my values folder. How do I tell my application to do this without re-instantiating the resources configurations ?

Comment: @user2247689: Beats me. Perhaps they should not be Android resources in the first place, but rather in something else (e.g., assets) that you manage yourself. The Android resource system is designed around giving you easy access to the proper resources for the device's current configuration, but offers nothing to allow you to access resources for any other configuration.

Comment: hmmm ... got myself into a difficult situation I guess ... well anyways thank you for helping :) btw I have referenced to tons of your answers :)

Answer (score 1):

To access resources from a different configuration:

```
Resources res_curr_conf = getResources();
Configuration c = new Configuration(res_curr_conf.getConfiguration());
c.locale = whateverLocaleIWant();
Resources res_alt_conf = new Resources(res_curr_conf.getAssets(), res_curr_conf.getDisplayMetrics(), c);
// TODO - use res_alt_conf
```